# Adblock Plus blocking a lot of ads on webpages that don't even have ads?

Tags: web-applications, malware, privacy

I was just checking my own website and noticed that Adblock Plus v1.9 blocked 13 ads on one of my pages and another 4 on one other. This is interesting to me because I have no ads on my site.

I'm running Chromium v43 and have my own web host.

UPDATE: I just checked my sites and now its blocking one ad on one and none on the other. This thing's counter is either haywire or was possibly blocking ads that followed me from a previous site.

On a side note, sometimes it will block approx. 50-60 ads on any given YouTube page.

Comment: Read the rules list which your AdBlock plus is subscribed to and see if any of those rules match elements which your website uses. If you have social media stuff then I would imagine it's getting blocked as well.

Comment: Do you by chance have any custom rules (e.g. from Ad Block Custom Element Helper), some of which would cause it to block elements on your web site?

Comment: Lots of little tracker codes installed on your website? Running AddThis? The javascript spew of tracking done by that service is just amazing.

Comment: Side note comment: Adblock does not per se block 50-60 ads on youtube. Youtube tries to send a ping back to the ad-server every 6 seconds or so. This ping is blocked by adblock, and you can see the adblock-counter increase every time this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Adblock blocks html code that is extremely similar to the code found on ads. So it is possible you have code that looks like ads? Could try and change your code around and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 2):

You should [investigate](http://support.getadblock.com/discussions/questions/274-what-ads-have-been-blocked) as to which ads are being blocked. Then the question might turn into: "Adblock blocks a lot of resources that aren't ads".

Comment: **Not ads** was instead, tracker resources on one site I was auditing. There were about 12 of the things there leeching information. Run EFF Privacy Badger sometime. One site had a count of 52 items which caused the HS meter to go "Wow!".